# Wordpress WooCommerce: Target successful add to cart action

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to do a few things with javascript once a product is added to your cart from the shop list view. Currently the 'View Cart' button gets a class ('added'), and that gives it a checkmark, but I want to change the text to 'Added to cart' as well as show another button.

The closest answer I've found online is:

```
$('body').on('added_to_cart',function(){
    // action here
});
```

But that only gives you the body element to work with.

The following does what I want, but there is no check whether or not the item was actually added to your cart successfully:

```
$('.add_to_cart_button').click(function(){
        $(this).text('Added to Cart');
        $(this).siblings('.view-cart').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's anyway to check the cart contents in javascript, but you could fire an AJAX call to the backend that would return true if the object is actually in the cart. It's a little more in depth, but at least you'd know for sure whether the product is in the cart.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's probably the ideal way to do it, but I'm unsure how. Do you have any links or a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it works.

Here is the jQuery code to send the AJAX request. If `ajax_object` is undefined, you'll have to make sure it gets localized with the script. I've included some notes at the end. The action will make sure that WordPress hooks onto the correct function. You may need to change the assignment for `product_id`, I'm not sure how the product is listed on your front end. You should also add functionality to handle AJAX errors.

```
var product_id = $(this).attr('data-product_id');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
    data: {'action':'is_in_cart', 'product_id': product_id},
    success: function(result) {
        if (result == true)
            console.log('In the cart!');
        else
            console.log('Not in the cart...');
    }
});
```

Here's the PHP code. You have to hook the `is_in_cart` function onto the WordPress AJAX actions. Then, you can just loop through the contents of the cart and see if the product ID you passed is in there. The second call to `add_action` allows users that aren't logged in to hook into this function as well.

```
function is_in_cart() {
    $searchFor = $_POST['product_id'];

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];

        if( $searchFor == $_product->id ) {  
            echo true;
        }
    }
    echo false;
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_is_in_cart', 'is_in_cart' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_is_in_cart', 'is_in_cart' );
```

If you don't already have your AJAX url available in JavaScript, you should include something like this when you localize the script. Then you'll be able to reference the `ajax_object` in JavaScript. Just make sure you change the script handle (`ajax-script`) to whatever it is in your instance.

```
wp_localize_script(
    'ajax-script',
    'ajax_object',
    array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    )
);
```